# Batch Update for 700+ items failing

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, image, batch

I have written a code that gets all the URLs from the URL column in a document library , converts them into base64 and stores the resultant string in the respective column.

The code works fine on a few list items , However fails for 700+ items without any errors.

Checked the network trace and found the below

**1. Images being fetched**

[image: Images being fetched]

**2. Only 100 List Items out of 700+ Updated as shown below**

[image]

**3. Found the below entry in network tab , not sure what this means. The executions stops at this point and doesn't proceed further**

[image]

The end goal here is to convert all the URLs in the URL column to base64 and store it in the base64 column against every entry in the document library.

Can anyone here suggest how this needs to be handled and if it is possible to skip the entries that cause errors at the time of execution and proceed further?

Below is the code

**Get all the list items**

```
function GetItemId() {
            //debugger;
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('DBSDistributorList')/Items?$select=ID,BaseURL,DistributorLogo",
                method: "GET",
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                    $.each(result.d.results, function (index, row) {
                        UpdateListItemUsingItemId(row["ID"], row["DistributorLogo"]["Url"]);

                    });


                },
                error: function (result) {
                    deferred.reject(result);
                }
            }); // Ajax list items

            return deferred.promise();

        };
```

Update all the list Items

```
function UpdateListItemUsingItemId(Id, dLogo) {
            //var deferred = $.Deferred();
            convertImgToBase64URL(dLogo, function (base64Img) {
                //console.log(base64Img);
                var _listItem = {
                    "__metadata": { 'type': 'SP.Data.DBSDistributorListItem' },

                    "BaseURL": base64Img
                };


                $.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('DBSDistributorList')/Items(" + Id + ")",
                    method: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    async: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify(_listItem),
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-Http-Method": "MERGE",
                        "If-Match": "*"
                    },
                    success: onSuccess,
                    error: onError
                    /*success: function (data) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        deferred.reject(err);
                    }*/   
                });
                //return deferred.promise();        
         });
       
        function onSuccess(data) {
           console.log('List Item Updated');
        }

        function onError(error) {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
      
   };
```

Conversion to base64

```
function convertImgToBase64URL(url, callback, outputFormat) {
        
             var canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
             var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
             ctx.clearRect( 0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height );
             ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
             ctx.fillRect(0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height);

            var img = new Image();
            img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
            img.onload = function () {
                //var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
                   // ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dataURL;
                canvas.height = img.height;
                canvas.width = img.width;
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
                callback(dataURL);
                canvas = null;
            };
            img.src = url;
        }
```

Would be grateful if anyone could help me with this.

Also please let me know if any other details are required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Lists/GetByTitle()/Items only returns the first 100 results. This is stated in the documentation here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#working-with-list-items-by-using-rest You need to implement paging to fetch the next page

Comment: @RobertLindgren Thank you for the comment , Do you have a sample code snippet by any chance for this scenario?

Comment: @Vivek what is the error?  Can't help unless we know what the error is.  Also, you could put in some `console.log()` statements to help keep track of where in the process it is, for instance right at the beginning of  `GetAllItems(requestUrl)` you could `console.log("get all items called with url: " + requestUrl)`.  Also you could add in other `console.log()` lines in some of the other `fail` handlers or even in the `done` handlers to track progress and see where the error is coming from.

Comment: @DylanCristy Thanks for replying . Managed to get it to work , However the process seems to be slower when compared to the actual code I wrote. Can we speedup the process by any chance? Since this is a lengthy process , Can you please let me know what would be the best place to add an alert when the process completes?

Comment: When you say compared to the code you wrote, do you mean the code where you were stuck with the 100 item limit, or the code where you used `$top=1000` to get all the items?  Because I think clearly doing all the stuff that's required to convert to base64 (create a canvas element, create an `Image` object, etc) is going to take longer when you do that 700 times vs. just 100 times.  If you want to know just how long it took to do the recursive requests to get all the items, add `console.log("retrieved all items: " + allItems.length)` right before the `UpdateFormDigest`

Comment: That way at least you will see the point just after retrieving all items and just before beginning all your processing and updating.  If you want to know when the entire process (including all updates etc) is done, you are going to have to do more complex code flow handling around your `$.each()` loop and your `UpdateListItemUsingItemId` function so you can track when all of those actions complete.  That is probably a separate question.

Comment: @DylanCristy Thank you for the response. Yes was talking about the $top=1000 part of the code , However it failed because of request digest which your code handles well. Also yes this is a time consuming process because of multiple actions happening in the code lifecycle . Appreciate all the help and knowledge sharing from your end :)

Comment: @DylanCristy I am getting request digest error while trying to update 16k records. It started failing from 6K , also the code just copies one column value to another without any conversion. Below is the error

"The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please post that as a separate question.  You can link back to this question if you would like to show that it is related.

Comment: @DylanCristy Posted as a separate question
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/290646/batch-update-for-16k-items-failing

Would appreciate if you could guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query to SharePoint reaches that 100 item limit, SharePoint provides you with the URL you need to get the next batch of items in it's response, in a property called `__next` that is right alongside the `results` array:

[image: screenshot of JSON result with __next property]

So what you need to do is make your function that requests all the list items recursive, and make it

1. Take the URL it should use as an argument
2. Check the results for a `__next` property
3. If the `__next` property is there, call itself using that URL

This also means moving the initial URL you want to start off with outside of that function.  At it's simplest level using your code example, you'd want to do something like this:

```
// remake your function to accept the URL it should use as an argument
function GetItemId(requestUrl) {
    //debugger;
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUrl, // use the URL that was passed in
        method: "GET",
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result);
            $.each(result.d.results, function (index, row) {
                UpdateListItemUsingItemId(row["ID"], row["DistributorLogo"]["Url"]);
            });
            
            // if there's a __next property,
            // call the function to get the next batch
            // by using the provided URL
            if (result.d.__next) {
                GetItemId(result.d.__next);
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            deferred.reject(result);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise();
};

////
////
// wherever in your code you actually make the call to that function,
// build the initial URL and call your function
var initialUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('DBSDistributorList')/Items?$select=ID,BaseURL,DistributorLogo";
GetItemId(initialUrl);
```

Personally though, I'd clean it up a little.  Things are getting confusing in there. I'm not sure why you want to make that call non-async. Also, you are resolving your `deferred` before you even do your update processing.  And with the addition I put in there to recursively call `GetItemID`, it now makes it so that you are doing the update processing in batches while simultaneously requesting the next batch of items.  Very confusing.

So I'd clean it up so that you move the update processing out of that, so that you can cleanly get all the items before you start processing.  And I'd let it be async, like it wants to be, and you don't need the `content-type` header on a `GET` request...  here's how I'd put it together:

```
function GetAllItems(requestUrl) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    }).done(function (thisResult) {
        if (thisResult.d.__next) {
            // if the __next property is present,
            // that measn that there's more to get,
            // so don't start resolving things yet,
            // just make the next request
            var nextRequest = GetAllItems(thisResult.d.__next);
            
            // since GetAllItems returns a promise,
            // we have to wait for that promise to resolve
            // before resolving the promise we made 
            // at the beginning of this function
            nextRequest.done(function(nextResult) {
                // nextResult should be a plain array of items,
                // so we need to combine that with the array
                // of items we got in this call in thisResult.d.results
                var combinedResults = thisResult.d.results.concat(nextResult);
                
                // then resolve the combined results back up to the next level
                deferred.resolve(combinedResults);

            }).fail(function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        } else {
            // __next doesn't exist, so
            // there's nothing more to get, so
            // start resolving the nested promises
            deferred.resolve(thisResult.d.results);
        }
    }).fail(function (result) {
        deferred.reject(result);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
};

//// (somewhere else in your code)
////
// from wherever you want to start off the process,
// build the initial URL
var initialUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('DBSDistributorList')/Items?$select=ID,BaseURL,DistributorLogo";

// start the process
var getAllItemsRequest = GetAllItems(initialUrl);

// wait for it all to complete
getAllItemsRequest.done(function (allItems) {
    // allItems should now be
    // an array of all 700+ items

    // make sure your request digest value is good
    // using the built-in SP provided function for doing just that
    UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, _spFormDigestRefreshInterval);
    
    // begin update processing
    $.each(allItems, function (index, row) {
        UpdateListItemUsingItemId(row["ID"], row["DistributorLogo"]["Url"]);
    });
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.warn("Error getting all items");
    console.warn(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail explanation , appreciate it. Actually I'm new to coding hence my code is not up to the mark :) . As a workaround , I used &top=1000 to get all the list items , then I got 403 request digest error . Would this code handle 403 error as well?

Comment: No, this code does not have anything specific to handle (or prevent) 403 errors.  If you are getting a request digest error, I would call `UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, _spFormDigestRefreshInterval)`  just _before_ you start your update processing, meaning just before the `$.each()`.  You could do it inside the `UpdateListItemUsingItemId()` function, but then that would mean you are refreshing the form digest 700+ times, which seems excessive.

Comment: @Vivek updated my answer with where I would put the call to `UpdateFormDigest()`

Comment: Thanks a lot Dylan for the help . I am trying the code you provided :)

Comment: I rewrote the code as per your suggestions , However I am still facing challenges getting it to work . I have updated my post under "UPDATED ANSWER" . Would appreciate if you could take a look and let me know.